# mod_rewrite redirect specific .asp pages back to original server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I  need to redirect traffic for a section of a redeveloped site back to the original site with apache mod_rewrite rules. I need to redirect all requests starting with http://www.example.com/page.asp back to the original site http://www.original.com/page.asp with the query string or anything following page.asp intact.

This seems simple enough, however I have had no luck with mod_rewrite generators or documentation on the web. My latest stab at the problem looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.asp(.*)$ http://www.original.com/page\.asp$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I appreciate any insight into correcting this mod_rewrite rule. Other redirects are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the rewrite to function properly using:

```
RewriteRule ^/page(.+)  http://www.original.com/page$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I found this apache doc helpful: [Resource Moved to Another Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs)